# Why My Shoutcast Fragment App gets a Fatal NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fragment

I have a problem and I hope someone out there will be able to help. I am a new learner of Android Studio and I am trying to convert an activity to a fragment.

Its been days and I have looked everywhere for a solution with no luck. 
Can somebody please explain to me why am I getting this FATAL ERROR on this line:

**LOG**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.support.android.designlibdemo, PID: 23057
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                  at com.support.android.designlibdemo.NewFragment.onCreateView(NewFragment.java:82)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2209)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:719)
                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:789)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1060)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3158)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2595)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1842)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1438)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7398)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                at android.view.C
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23057 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

**Java Code**

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment {



@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;

@BindView(R.id.playTrigger)
ImageButton trigger;

@BindView(R.id.list_views)
ListView listView;

@BindView(R.id.name)
TextView textView;

@BindView(R.id.sub_player)
View subPlayer;

RadioManager radioManager;

String streamURL;


private Toolbar supportActionBar;





@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new, container, false);


    ButterKnife.bind(getActivity());

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    radioManager = RadioManager.with(getContext());

    listView.setAdapter(new ShoutcastListAdapter(this, ShoutcastHelper.retrieveShoutcasts(getContext())));  //This is the ERROR line

    return view;
}




@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

}

@Override
public void onStop() {

    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);

    super.onStop();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    radioManager.unbind();

    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    radioManager.bind();

}



@Subscribe
public void onEvent(String status){

    switch (status){

        case PlaybackStatus.LOADING:

            // loading

            break;

        case PlaybackStatus.ERROR:

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.no_stream, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;

    }

    trigger.setImageResource(status.equals(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING)
            ? R.drawable.ic_pause_black
            : R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black);

}

@OnClick(R.id.playTrigger)
public void onClicked(){

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(streamURL)) return;

    radioManager.playOrPause(streamURL);

}



@OnItemClick(R.id.list_views)
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

    Shoutcast shoutcast = (Shoutcast) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if(shoutcast == null){

        return;

    }

    textView.setText(shoutcast.getName());

    subPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    streamURL = shoutcast.getUrl();

   radioManager.playOrPause(streamURL);
}

public void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar supportActionBar) {
    this.supportActionBar = supportActionBar;
}
```

}

**Fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_views"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sub_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:text="Radio station"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/playTrigger"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black"
            android:background="@null"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Old code changed to a fragment**
This is the same code I am changing to a fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;

@BindView(R.id.playTrigger)
ImageButton trigger;

@BindView(R.id.listview)
ListView listView;

@BindView(R.id.name)
TextView textView;

@BindView(R.id.sub_player)
View subPlayer;

RadioManager radioManager;

String streamURL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    radioManager = RadioManager.with(this);

    listView.setAdapter(new ShoutcastListAdapter(this, ShoutcastHelper.retrieveShoutcasts(this)));
}

@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

}

@Override
public void onStop() {

    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);

    super.onStop();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    radioManager.unbind();

    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    radioManager.bind();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finish();

}

@Subscribe
public void onEvent(String status){

    switch (status){

        case PlaybackStatus.LOADING:

            // loading

            break;

        case PlaybackStatus.ERROR:

            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_stream, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;

    }

    trigger.setImageResource(status.equals(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING)
            ? R.drawable.ic_pause_black
            : R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black);

}

@OnClick(R.id.playTrigger)
public void onClicked(){

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(streamURL)) return;

    radioManager.playOrPause(streamURL);

}

@OnItemClick(R.id.listview)
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

    Shoutcast shoutcast = (Shoutcast) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if(shoutcast == null){

        return;

    }

    textView.setText(shoutcast.getName());

    subPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    streamURL = shoutcast.getUrl();

    radioManager.playOrPause(streamURL);

}
```

}

I really am not sure why its doing that. Its an app I am doing for a local radio station and I want to have a player on the fragment. Also I have double checked the id's of my resources several time and tried renaming some...still no luck. Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: have you debugged and checked which instance variable is null?

Comment: Thanks Mike. Will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

> ButterKnife.bind(getActivity());

to

> ButterKnife.bind(this,view);

Answer (score 0):

`listView` is not found because you have bind ButterKnife with the activity not fragment. For fragment you have to use `ButterKnife.bind(this, view)` instead of `ButterKnife.bind(getActivity())`

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment{
    // as other code

    @BindView(R.id.listview)
    ListView listView;

    // as other code

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        // other codes
    }
}
```